# fget shows incorrect output to browser for different languages

Tags: php, character-encoding, fgets

I am getting content from my_file.php file using `fgets` the content in my_file.php is in cz language as

```
"Overte svuj úcet";
```

but after getting and `print_r` browser shows

```
"OvÄ›Å™te svÅ¯j ÃºÄet"
```

but if I echo "Overte svuj úcet"; browser show correct output

```
"Overte svuj úcet";
```

actually I want to generate a **csv** file for different languages though I set `charset='utf-8'` but not success I also googled but no solution found.

Comment: Which encoding is used for the CZ language in that file? You need to share that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay after a long search i found it and this solved my problem

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/downloads

Comment: Yes this library is the best option for you if you want to generate spreadsheet files involving multiple languages.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a simple encoding mismatch. The data is in encoding A, but the browser tries to read it as encoding B. `fgets` does not do anything with encodings, it just reads the raw bytes from the file, nothing more, nothing less. If you are not transcoding the data either, there's nothing wrong with the text itself.

This only leaves the browser, which is interpreting the data incorrectly. What you should always do is output an HTTP header that specifies the encoding:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You can also configure your web server to output this header by default. You probably set the HTML `<meta>` tag to denote UTF-8, but are probably outputting the data before that tag.

Either way, make sure the HTTP header denotes the encoding the actual data is in.

Comment: okay i used header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); & now browser showing correct but my csv still saves wrong text 
OvÄ›Å™te svÅ¯j ÃºÄet

Comment: and also tried header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'); & now browser showing correct but my csv still saves wrong text 
OvÄ›Å™te svÅ¯j ÃºÄet

Comment: How are you testing that the CSV is "saved" incorrectly? Maybe you should start with [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) to better understand what's going on.